# How does a standby ResourceManager (RM) become active when RM HA is enabled in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I've gone through the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html) for RM HA. I understand the fundamentals, except one key part. When an active RM goes down, how do the standby RMs know that one of them needs to take over? Below is a relevant portion from the doc:

> The ZooKeeper state store achieves this implicit fencing through ACLs. All the ResourceManagers have shared read-write-admin access to the store, but only the Active has create-delete access. A ResourceManager claims this create-delete access while transitioning to Active. At this point, any other ResourceManager that previously had create-delete access loses access, fails to make changes to the store, and transitions itself to Standby. By having each ResourceManager create a dummy znode every so often (10 seconds, by default), a ResourceManager is always informed of its access to the store.

Does it mean that all the RMs periodically send messages to Zookeeper to get access to the `ZKResourceManagerStateStore`? And whoever gets the create-delete access assumes the role of Active?

**Update**: Found [this](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/what-is-zookeeper-and-its-use-case/) awesome article that explains how RM HA works in great detail. Keeping for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zookeeper is famous for its coordination. So, as you have read the document you mentioned the link in your question so I assume that you have read the part **Automatic Failover** .

Zookeeper maintains the Active-Standby High Availability through epoch number strategy. Both the RM goes for the leader election but only one with the minimum epoch number is chosen as the Leader. The RM doesn't need Zookeeper Failover Controller like Namenodes. The activestandbyelector is embedded in RMs by default.

That is why the leader writes to the Zookeeper and when it fails to write, Zookeeper assumes that the Active RM has become unresponsive and make the other RM new Leader.

Comment: Hi, can you please share any link, if possible, that explains the epoch number strategy?

Comment: here you go: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.8/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_atomicBroadcast